# Error when Running hector slam from home directory

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a launch file that calls hectormapping.launch and the geotiff_mapper.launch, these function correctly when the Hector SLAM stack is installed from repositories into "opt/ros.." directory.

In order to better understand the Hector SLAM stack I copied it in to my personal works space.
And now the same launch files produce the error:

```
[hector_geotiff_node-10] process has died [pid 18407, exit code 127, cmd nice -n 15 /home/samarth/workingspace/hector_slam/hector_geotiff/bin/geotiff_node map:=/dynamic_map __name:=hector_geotiff_node __log:=/home/samarth/.ros/log/dea32fec-7e09-11e2-9de0-90e6ba006a11/hector_geotiff_node-10.log]. 

log file: /home/samarth/.ros/log/dea32fec-7e09-11e2-9de0-90e6ba006a11/hector_geotiff_node-10*.log 

/home/samarth/workingspace/hector_slam/hector_geotiff/bin/geotiff_node: error while loading shared libraries: libgeotiff_writer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I open the “workingspace/hector_slam/hector_geotiff/lib” folder the libgeotiff_writer.so is present so Im not sure of what is going wrong.

I tried using rosmake on the packages within the HECTOR SLAM stack but that has not done anything.

Any ideas?
cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58859/error-when-running-hector-slam-from-home-directory../) by [samarth.rajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3637/samarth.rajan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your question it looks like you've copied the system package directly into your workspace. If this is not the case please ignore the rest of the answer.

To get the code in your local workspace, you should download it from source into your local workspace. On the corresponding wiki page (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_geotiff), the source repository is listed as "svn [https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_slam"](https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_slam%22). So you can use the following command to download it in your workspace:

```
svn checkout https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_slam
```

You'll then need to make to do the following:

1. Add the package to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH inside your ~/.bashrc
2. Get all the dependencies for this package. Since you have the system package installed as well, you can most likely skip this step.
3. Run "rosmake hector_geotiff"

You should be good to go then!

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samarth.rajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3637/samarth.rajan/) on 2013-03-22**:
Thanks Pyush. That seems to have done the trick : )

**Comment by [samarth.rajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3637/samarth.rajan/) on 2013-03-26**:
Just wondering, if i were to change the code in the package, would ros make be sufficient to recompile and build all the required files?